# Virtual machines lost internet after physical host upgrade

Tags: virtualization, dns, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge, virt-manager

I have a home server setup where Ubuntu 16.04 hosts a couple of Ubuntu server virtual machines. Everything ran smoothly for half a year until this week I installed the updates to the physical machine and after that the virtual machines lost their connection to internet.

Here are some details:

- I'm using Virtual Machine Manager to manage the VMs
- VMs are KVM
- The physical host is behind a NAT and the network should bridged to VMs
- VMs have static IP addresses
- I am seeing their IP and MAC addresses on my router's active client list
- I'm able to login via SSH to the VMs, but once in the VM is not able to ping anything (FQDNs nor direct IPs) nor reach apt repositories

**Here is the content of a VM's /etc/network/interfaces**:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
address 192.168.0.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

**VM's ifconfig:**

```
$ ifconfig

ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:5c:7c:8b
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe5c:7c8b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2855 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9564 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:54129 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:148974 (148.9 KB)  TX bytes:791122 (791.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:2270863 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:2270863 (2.2 MB)
```

**Some connectivity tests I ran:**

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'fi.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'fi.archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Working]^C
```

-

```
$ ping -v google.fi
^C
```

-

```
$ ping 172.217.18.3
PING 172.217.18.3 (172.217.18.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 172.217.18.3 ping statistics ---
26 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 25198ms
```

Any idea what more could I check to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I came to the conclusion that there must be something wrong with my bridge adapter. I ended up setting my bridge and network settings on the hypervisor from scratch and after a reboot all virtual machines were fully functioning again.

I have a hunch that a relatively fresh docker setup somehow conflicted with the parallel virtual infrastructure, but I failed to find the actual problem in the configuration so I cannot be 100% sure.

Anyway, this time the solution was a fresh build of a bridge configuration.